# How to match the absence of the array elements in perl?

Tags: arrays, regex, perl

I am trying to match the absence word on the data by using array elements.
My code is

```
use warnings;
use strict;
my @ar = qw(one two three four five six seven eight nine ten);
my @data = <DATA>;
print "Absence word in the data\n";
foreach my $mat(@ar){
    my $nonmatch;
    foreach my $dat (@data){
        $nonmatch = grep{m/(?!$mat)/} $dat;
    }
    print "$nonmatch\n";
}
__DATA__
eight two four one two three four seven eight ten one two seven
```

First refer the array element value on the data array element is absent in the data that only print on.

I expected output is:

```
Absence word in the data
five
six
nine
```

How can i do it

Comment: It would be to use a hash for the words in `@data` so then you can just check whether `$mat` exists in the hash or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a seen style hash as modeled in [perlfaq4 - How can I tell whether a certain element is contained in a list or array?](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4.html#How-can-I-tell-whether-a-certain-element-is-contained-in-a-list-or-array%3f)

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my %seen = map { $_ => 1 } map { split ' ' } <DATA>;

my @ar = qw(one two three four five six seven eight nine ten);

print "Absence word in the data\n";
print "$_\n" for grep { !$seen{$_} } @ar;

__DATA__
eight two four one two three four seven eight ten one two seven
```

Outputs:

```
Absence word in the data
five
six
nine
```

Comment: Do you need to `chomp` your `<DATA>`? Or, will the split remove the NL on the end?

Comment: No need to `chomp`.  `split` or `split ' '` are special cases that are treated like `split /\s+/` with the additional feature that any preceding spacing is removed.  There would potentially be a trailing `''` after the split, but only if we used a negative limit.

Answer (score 1):

You can use hash slice `@seen{@r}` to store all seen words from `@r` in `%seen` hash, and check later these hash keys against `@ar` array,

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my @ar = qw(one two three four five six seven eight nine ten);
my %seen;
while (my $mat = <DATA>) {
    my @r = split (' ', $mat);
    @seen{@r} = ();
}
print "Absence word in the data\n";
print "$_\n" for grep { not exists $seen{$_} } @ar;

__DATA__
eight two four one two three four seven eight ten one two seven
```

output

```
Absence word in the data
five
six
nine
```

Comment: Thank you @mpapec This is working Please explain your code. I am not get a idea about declaring the hasesh?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a question I had at one point, and the code I came up with was the following code which I created based on the information at this page:

https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/perl-cookbook/1565922433/ch04s08.html

```
# assume @A and @B are already loaded

%seen  = ();                     # lookup table to test membership of B
@aonly = ();                     # answer

# build lookup table
$seen{$_} = 1 for @B;

# find elements only in @A and not in @B
for ( @A ) {
    push @aonly, $_ unless $seen{$_};
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a hash containing all words from the `__DATA__` as keys (can be done in one line using hash slice), then filter the words not in hash (can be also done in one line using `grep`).

```
use warnings;
use strict;
my @ar = qw(one two three four five six seven eight nine ten);

my $data = join '', (<DATA>);
my @data_words = split ' ', $data;  # get a list of words

my %data;
@data{@data_words} = @data_words;   # fill a hash with the words from __DATA__

my @missing = grep { !exists $data{$_}; } @ar; # filter words

print "Absence word in the data: @missing\n";

__DATA__
eight two four one two three four seven eight ten one two seven
```

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

Always [chomp](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html) what you read in. This includes `__DATA__`:

```
my @data = <DATA>;   # The NL is in each element
chomp @data;         # Now it isn't!
```

If you don't chomp, you'll be checking to see if `one` matches `one\n`. Also, since you put the entire `__DATA__` on one line, it will be read as a single line of input. You'll have to use [split](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) to separate it out into an array.

Second thing: Usually, when you ask *is this in that lis?t* type of questions, you should immediately think of hashes. A hash can quickly be used to look up an item. In this case, you'd make a hash of your data, and then verify if each item in your list is in that hash:

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl
#

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(say);

my @list = qw(one two three four five six seven eight nine ten);
my @data = <DATA>;
chomp @data;        # Don't forget!

#
# Translate your input as a hash
#

my %data_hash;
for my $element (@data) {
    $data_hash{$element} = 1;
}

for my $element (@list) {
    if ( not exists $data_hash{$element} ) {
        say "$element isn't in the list";
    }
}
__DATA__
eight
two
four
one
two
three
four
seven
eight
ten
one
two
seven
```

Note that the [map](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html) command gives you a shorter way of writing this loop:

```
#
# Translate your input as a hash
#

my %data_hash;
for my $element (@data) {
    $data_hash{$element} = 1;
}
```

Can now be shortened to a single line:

```
#
# Translate your input as a hash
#

my %data_hash =  map { $_ => 1 } @data;
```

This is a common way of turning an array into a hash, so most developers will simply use it.

Answer (score 0):

This solution starts with a list of things you are looking for and drops anything you see along the way, then prints what's left.

You can optimize this for large data by checking at the bottom of the while loop if there are still any keys in the `%unseen` hash.  I added another line, and the word "sixteen" to your test data to make sure it worked with multiple lines and that we didn't get a false positive for "six" there.

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my @to_match = qw/ one two three four five six seven eight nine ten /;
my %unseen;
$unseen{$_} = 1 for @to_match;
while (my $line = <DATA>) {
    foreach my $match_this (@to_match) {
        delete $unseen{$match_this} if $line =~/\b$match_this\b/;
    }
}
print "Words absent from the data:\n". join "\n", keys %unseen;
print "\n";
__DATA__
eight two four one two three four seven eight ten one two seven
sixteen
```

Comment: Please comment when downvoting--this solution is a different approach with a useful possible optimization--I didn't test extensively but I believe it does work.